# Detecting a subset of special characters php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string and the validity of the string is defined as:

1. The string can have alphanumeric characters or (_) or (.) or (-).
2. No other special characters are allowed.

Is there a way to allow only certain special characters in php??

Comment: /W checks for anything except a-z|A-Z|0-9 or _
but I want to allow (.) and (-) also

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code like this to `only allow` a text with your allowed character set:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\w.-]+$/', $str))
    echo "valid $str\n";
else
    echo "invalid $str\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try looping through each character in the string and checking it individually

```
for($i = strlen($string); $i >= 0; $i--)
{
    $check = $string[$i];
    if(ctype_alnum($check) || $check == "_" || $check == "." || $check == "-")
    {
        //Code if good

    }
    else
    {
        //Code if bad
    }
}
```